# Rebuilding instance in amazon aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How i can Rebuilding instance in amazon AWS

In digitalocean, it's possible but i don't find like this in AWS

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The concept of *Rebuilding* is different between Digital Ocean and AWS. Please provide more details of what you wish to accomplish on AWS, and then we can recommended options.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein sometimes I need to reset the instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an AMI of your machine. which in turn can be used to launch new instances.

Reference:-

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html

Answer (score 2):

The concept of Rebuilding is different in DigitalOcean and AWS. If you want to rebuild your instances in AWS you will need to terminate the instance and launch another one, changing anything you need. But if you want to rebuild an instance with the same configuration with less work, check if AWS CloudFormation fits for you.

https://aws.amazon.com/pt/documentation/cloudformation/